# NAs in output of rowSums()

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate sums for each row with `rowSums()` but in the output is NA  is  included.

```
data$Variable <- rowSums(subset(data, select = c("v1", "v2", "v3", na.rm = TRUE)

str(data$Variable)
```

What could be the reason ?

It appears in output regardless of whether I use  "na.rm = TRUE" or  "na.rm = FALSE",

Comment: `rowSums(subset(data, select = c("v1", "v2", "v3")), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset using `dput(x)`?

Answer (score 0):

The inherent problem in your code is the use of parentheses. You haven't closed the argument properly and `na.rm = T` is supplied to `c()` whereas it should be supplied to `rowSums()`. Below is an example of a working code. You can modify it to your need.

```
tab <- matrix(c(7, 5, NA, 19, NA, 2, 17, 6, 12, 10, 7, 9), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(tab) <- c('colName1','colName2','colName3')
rownames(tab) <- c('rowName1','rowName2','rowName3')

tab <- as.table(tab)

print(tab)

sumRows = rowSums(tab[,c('colName2', 'colName3')], na.rm = T)

print(sumRows)
```